# Show two plots together: a two dimensional curve tangent to the maxima of a three dimensional plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list containing `3` columns and `6552` rows which can be found [here](https://ufile.io/xsleyvmr).

The plot of data is shown below:

[image]

We have a cross cut for a specific value of `y`, for example, `y=0.01 or y=1.26` over this plot by (`mathematica.dat` is the uploaded file):

```
data3D = Import["mathematica.dat", "Table"];
yequalto01 = Rest /@ (Select[data3D, #[[1]] == 0.01 &]);
yequalto126 = Rest /@ (Select[data3D, #[[1]] == 1.26 &]);
```

From a two column data (`yequalto01`,`yequalto126`) we can extract the peaks by
`peakValues = Pick[yequalto01, PeakDetect[yequalto01[[;; , 2]]], 1];`

This list except the last pair can be presented as

```
peakValues ={{0.0, 1.000}, {4.4, 0.982}, {8.9, 0.961}, {13.3, 0.942}, {17.8, 0.923}, {22.2, 0.906}};
```

We plotted `peakValues` and drawn `data3D` separately. But, I wish to show two plots simultaneous in one figure as the below one which prepared by paint (blue and purple curves are tangent to the peaks of the 3D plot).

[image]

Comment: You can combine plots using `Show`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
peakValues01 = 
  Pick[yequalto01, PeakDetect[yequalto01[[;; , 2]]], 1][[;; -2]];
peakValues126 = 
  Pick[yequalto126, PeakDetect[yequalto01[[;; , 2]]], 1][[;; -2]];

p01 = Join[{ConstantArray[0.01, Length[peakValues01]]}, 
    peakValues01\[Transpose]]\[Transpose];
p126 = Join[{ConstantArray[1.26, Length[peakValues126]]}, 
    peakValues126\[Transpose]]\[Transpose];


Show[
 ListPlot3D[data3D],
 ListPointPlot3D[p01],
 Graphics3D@Line@p01,
 ListPointPlot3D[p126],
 Graphics3D@Line@p126
 ]
```

> [image]

Of course, you can customise the lines/dots as you want with the standard options.
If you want smooth lines between the points, I would try with interpolating first and then a ParametricPlot:

```
p01f[x_] = Interpolation[peakValues01][x];
p126f[x_] = Interpolation[peakValues126][x];

htl = Join[{#*\[Pi], #*\[Pi], {0.014, 0}} & /@ 
    Range[0, 8, 2], {#*\[Pi], "", {0.01, 0}} & /@ Range[0, 8, 1]];

Show[
 ListPlot3D[data3D, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Mesh -> None
  , Ticks -> {Automatic, htl, Automatic}, BoxStyle -> Dashed, 
  AxesLabel -> {"y", "x"}],
 ListPointPlot3D[p01, PlotStyle -> {Purple}],
 ListPointPlot3D[p126, PlotStyle -> {Blue}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{0.01, x, p01f[x]}, {x, 0., 25.1}, {y, 0, 1.26}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Purple, Thickness[0.02]}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{1.26, x, p126f[x]}, {x, 0., 25.1}, {y, 0, 1.26}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.02]}],
 ViewPoint -> {4, 1, 1}
 ]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

```
{y01, y126} = Table[Select[data3D, #[[1]] == i &], {i, {.01, 1.26}}];

{peaks01, peaks126} = Pick[#, PeakDetect[#[[;; , 3]]], 1] & /@ {y01, y126};

Show[ListPlot3D[data3D], 
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Thick, Red, Line @ peaks01, Point @ peaks01,
   Green, Line @ peaks126, Point@ peaks126}]]
```

[image]